# Mounting drive not getting full access

Tags: samba, read-only

I am having problem with mounting.. I bought iOmega Storage box ix200.
I shared a folder from iOmega box for 10 users.

I mounted this shared drive in all 10 Virtual machines by editing /etc/fstab file. After rebooting the drive got mounted. But when a user accessing it and tries to create a new file it shows lock symbol on it.

But if i try to access this drive from Menu - Location and, from there put File server IP and do then i am able to create a file without lock symbol. It's opening read-only for all the users.

This is happening for all the users except 1 user.
If i assign that user then its working fine. Can someone guide me what may be the issue.

---

Hi Thanks for your response. Please find below information

```
    root@JHSP-Christopher:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d82e0cc6-4bff-4dba-89af-1d5965057568 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=041df524-1e47-4ba2-9046-1f8aee0870ad none            swap    sw              0       0

//192.168.1.150/worksdaily /media/JHSP-FS smbfs username=christopher,password=chh156 rw 0 0
//192.168.1.150/christopher /media/Christopher smbfs username=christopher,password=chh156 rw 0 0
root@JHSP-Christopher:~# mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
//192.168.1.150/christopher on /media/Christopher type cifs (rw)
//192.168.1.150/worksdaily on /media/JHSP-FS type cifs (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/jhsp/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jhsp)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/christopher/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=christopher)
root@JHSP-Christopher:~# ls -ld $(mount | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
drwxr-xr-x  23 root        root        4096 Dec 19 19:18 /
drwxr-xr-x  14 root        root        4080 Jan  6 19:10 /dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /dev/pts
drwx------   2 christopher christopher 4096 Dec 20 00:13 /home/christopher/.gvfs
drwx------   2 jhsp        jhsp        4096 Dec 18 15:02 /home/jhsp/.gvfs
drwxrwxrwx   2          99 users          0 Jan  5 14:40 /media/Christopher
drwxrwxrwx   6          99 users          0 Jan  7 17:51 /media/JHSP-FS
dr-xr-xr-x 232 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /proc
drwxr-xr-x  23 root        root         980 Jan 11 19:50 /run
drwxrwxrwt   3 root        root          60 Jan 11 17:35 /run/lock
drwxrwxrwt   2 root        root         320 Jan 11 19:36 /run/shm
drwxr-xr-x  13 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /sys
drwxr-xr-x   4 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /sys/fs/fuse/connections
drwx------  14 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /sys/kernel/debug
drwxr-xr-x   3 root        root           0 Jan  6 19:10 /sys/kernel/security
```

Comment: The lines that you use to mount your shares would be nice...

Comment: Please add to your question the output of the following commands: `cat /etc/fstab`, `mount` and `ls -ld $(mount | cut -d ' ' -f 3)`

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a problem in `fstab` entries. Check out `4th column` for mount options and ensure that it is not in `ro`. That means read-only. If it is so, then change it to `rw`- read write.